# How can I detect the file is forbidden when using open() in linux

Tags: c, linux

What does open() return when I am try open a file without permisson?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)?

Comment: Null pointer if it fails to open a file

Comment: @chouaib This is `open`, not `fopen`.

Comment: oh sorry for not paying attention

Answer (score 4):

When an error occurs while using open function, the file descriptor is set to -1.

To find out the specific error you need to check ERRNO. (this will have different values depending on the error occurred) in your case it will be EACCESS.

This would be the code,

```
fd = open ("file.txt",O_RDONLY);

if (fd == -1)
{
    if (ERRNO == EACCES)
    {
        printf ("Permission denied \n");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The usual habit is to display some error and `errno` related message using either `perror` or `strerror(errno)`